# Initialize java clock using constructors

Tags: java, constructor, current-time

I have a class called Clock. It calculates the time taken. In my project,it is a requirement to use constructors to initialize the starting time. When I used constructors, it ended up in always giving me time = 0.0 ms. Can anybody help me sort this out?

Clock.java

```
public class Clock {

private long start;

public Clock() {
    start = 0;
}
public Clock(String s) {
    start = s;
}

public void start() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public double stop() {
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double time = stop - start;
    return time;
}

}
```

Part of the code I am calling in another class. c is an object instantiated from class Clock.java

```
    public static void insertion(Clock c, Sort s, Scanner sc) throws IOException {
    for (int count = 0; count < 11; count++) {
        String path[] = selectPath(count);
        String filepath = path[0];
        int num = Integer.parseInt(path[1]);
        int[] NumArrays = populate(filepath, num);
        c.start();
        s.insertionSort(NumArrays);
        double timeI = c.stop();
        System.out.println("Insertion sort took " + timeI + "ms for " + path[1] + " data");
    }
    menu(sc, c, s);
}
```

Comment: Constructors can have parameters.

Comment: I tried using explicit constructor too, but it is still giving me 0.0 ms.

Comment: Show us how you use constructor with a parameter.  Add it to your question by using [Edit].

Comment: The issue can't be the constructor, because it doesn't do anything different compared to a default constructor.

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited it.

Comment: Are you sure your method `insertionSort()` takes more thant 1ms?

Comment: Replacing the `s.insertionSort(NumArrays);` with `Thread.sleep(1000)` make it work for me.

Comment: The aim of the project is to calculate time taken for different algorithms to sort integers. I cannot omit s.insertionSort(NumArrays);

Comment: Show your main method or wherever else you instantiate your `Clock` object and call your `insertion()`  method.

Comment: Your code won't compile. `private long start; ... public Clock(String s) {start = s;}`